# Memory leak in SensorManager implementation in parent class

Tags: android, kotlin, memory-leaks, android-sensors, sensormanager

> I have handled screen orientation using SensorManager and it's working fine

But there is some memory leak as it is set in BaseActivity like

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SensorOrientationChangeNotifier.Listener  {
   override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        SensorOrientationChangeNotifier.getInstance(this)?.addListener(this)
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        SensorOrientationChangeNotifier.getInstance(this)?.remove(this)
    }
}
```

**SensorOrientationChangeNotifier.kt**

```
class SensorOrientationChangeNotifier private constructor(applicationContext: Context) {

    private val mListeners = ArrayList<WeakReference<Listener?>>(3)
    var orientation = 0
        private set
    private val mSensorEventListener: SensorEventListener
    private val mSensorManager: SensorManager

    init {
        mSensorEventListener = NotifierSensorEventListener()
        mSensorManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
    }

    /**
     * Call on activity reset()
     */
    private fun onResume() {
        mSensorManager.registerListener(
            mSensorEventListener,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL
        )
    }

    /**
     * Call on activity onPause()
     */
    private fun onPause() {
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorEventListener)
    }

    private inner class NotifierSensorEventListener : SensorEventListener {
        override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent) {
            val x = event.values[0]
            val y = event.values[1]
            var newOrientation: Int = orientation
            if (x < 5 && x > -5 && y > 5) newOrientation =
                0 else if (x < -5 && y < 5 && y > -5) newOrientation =
                90 else if (x < 5 && x > -5 && y < -5) newOrientation =
                180 else if (x > 5 && y < 5 && y > -5) newOrientation = 270


            ///Timber.v("Matas_mOrientation = "+ newOrientation+"   ["+event.values[0]+","+event.values[1]+","+event.values[2]+"]");
            if (orientation != newOrientation) {
                Timber.v("Matas_mOrientation-Orientation-> NEW")
                orientation = newOrientation
                notifyListeners()
            } else {
                ///Timber.v("Matas_mOrientation-Orientation-> OLD");
            }
        }

        override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor, accuracy: Int) {}
    }

    interface Listener {
        fun onOrientationChange(orientation: Int)
    }

    fun addListener(listener: Listener) {
        if (get(listener) == null) // prevent duplications
            mListeners.add(WeakReference(listener))
        if (mListeners.size == 1) {
            onResume() // this is the first client
        }
    }

    fun remove(listener: Listener) {
        val listenerWR = get(listener)
        remove(listenerWR)
    }

    private fun remove(listenerWR: WeakReference<Listener?>?) {
        if (listenerWR != null) mListeners.remove(listenerWR)
        if (mListeners.size == 0) {
            onPause()
        }
    }

    private operator fun get(listener: Listener): WeakReference<Listener?>? {
        for (existingListener in mListeners) if (existingListener.get() === listener) return existingListener
        return null
    }

    private fun notifyListeners() {
        val deadLiksArr = ArrayList<WeakReference<Listener?>>()
        for (wr in mListeners) {
            if (wr.get() == null) deadLiksArr.add(wr) else wr.get()!!
                .onOrientationChange(orientation)
        }

        // remove dead references
        for (wr in deadLiksArr) {
            mListeners.remove(wr)
        }
    }

    val isPortrait: Boolean = orientation == 0 || orientation == 180
    val isLandscape: Boolean = !isPortrait

    companion object {
        val TAG = javaClass.simpleName
        private var mInstance: SensorOrientationChangeNotifier? = null
        fun getInstance(applicationContext: Context): SensorOrientationChangeNotifier? {
            if (mInstance == null) mInstance = SensorOrientationChangeNotifier(applicationContext)
            return mInstance
        }
    }
}
```

I think my `context` is leaking as user switch from one activity to another But `mInstance` is not null due to singleton object

Can someone suggest a better approach to implement it once without memory leak in **BaseActivity**

I think I should directly pass **SensorManager** with `applicationContext`

```
     val sensorManager = applicationContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
     SensorOrientationChangeNotifier.getInstance(sensorManager)?.addListener(this)
```

Comment: How do you know you have a memory leak?

Comment: using leak canary

Comment: OK, and what is leaking? Can you attach some data or images?

Comment: Not related to your question, but Hungarian notation doesn't mesh well with Kotlin because Kotlin has properties, whose names are exposed publicly from classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `SensorOrientationChangeNotifier` class holds a reference to the Context you pass to it. Since you pass the Activity as your Context parameter, it is holding a reference to your Activity for as long as it is alive, which is forever since it is a singleton. You were *naming* your parameters `applicationContext` but in practice you were using an Activity instance instead.

To fix it, make sure you pull the `applicationContext` out of the Activity and use that. You can't leak the Application's Context, because it lasts for the lifetime of the application instance.

```
companion object {
    val TAG = javaClass.simpleName
    private var mInstance: SensorOrientationChangeNotifier? = null
    fun getInstance(context: Context): SensorOrientationChangeNotifier? {
        if (mInstance == null) mInstance = SensorOrientationChangeNotifier(context.applicationContext)
        return mInstance
    }
}
```

Also, there's no reason to be returning a nullable from your `getInstance()` function. And your `TAG` right now evaluates to `"Companion"`, which isn't very useful. Here it is with both of those things fixed:

```
companion object {
    val TAG = SensorOrientationChangeNotifier::class.simpleName
    private var instance: SensorOrientationChangeNotifier? = null
    fun getInstance(context: Context): SensorOrientationChangeNotifier {
        return instance ?: 
            SensorOrientationChangeNotifier(context.applicationContext).also { instance = it }
    }
}
```